# How to Prefix a column values with an apostrophe ( ' )?

Tags: linux, sed, awk, csv

I have a CSV file with multiple columns and 1000's of records, I need to prefix all the values of one of the columns (lets say 2nd column) with an apostrophe **`'`** except in the first line or header line, There might be an easy one liner for this. How could I achieve this using `awk` or `sed`? Please note, I might have multiple commas in the values which are enclosed in double quotes.

Sample data:

```
"col1","col2","col3","col4","col5"
"value11","value12","value13","value14","value15"
"value21","value22","value23","value24","value25"
"value31","value32","value33","value34","value35"
```

Expected output:

```
"col1","col2","col3","col4","col5"
"value11","'value12","value13","value14","value15"
"value21","'value22","value23","value24","value25"
"value31","'value32","value33","value34","value35"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sed:

```
sed '2,$s/^\("[^"]*","\)/\1'"'"/ test.in
```

Using EREs to get rid of some of the escaping:

```
sed -E '2,$s/^("[^"]*",")/\1'"'"/ test.in
```

awk:

```
awk -F, 'NR>1{sub(/^"/,"\"'"'"'",$2)}1' test.in
```

If you don't want to worry about the quoting, use the escape code:

```
awk -F, '{sub(/^"/,"\"\x27",$2)}1' test.in
```

Comment: Yeah, I considered looking up the escape code, but it's good practice for the OP to be careful with quoting.

Comment: I've got the escape code in mine.

Comment: @slm Yeah, but quotes are more fun :)

Comment: @Kevin - I couldn't figure them out quickly so went with the escape.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a gawk one:

```
$ gawk -F'","' -v var="'" -v OFS='","' 'NR>1{$2=var$2;} 1' foo.csv
```

The `-v` option lets you define variables that are accessible to the `gawk` script. In this case, `var` is `'` and `OFS` (the output field separator) is `","`, same as the input field separator (`-F`). We then check that this is not the first line (`NR>1`) and add the value of `var` to the second column.
Finally, the `1` is just a trick, it evaluates to true which makes `gawk` print the line. It is equivalent to adding a `print;` but shorter.

If you want to run this on a different column, just change `$2=var$2;` to `$N=var$N` where `N` is the column number you are interested in.

---

You can also do this in perl (naturally, you can do *everything* in perl):

```
$ perl -F'\",\"' -ane '$.>1 && do{$F[1]=chr(39).$F[1]}; 
                       print join("\",\"",@F)' foo.csv
```

The `-a` switch makes perl split input lines like gawk only that it saves them in the array `@F` (perl arrays start from 0, so the 2nd column will be `$F[1]`, the 3rd `$F[2]` etc.). The `-F` (again like `gawk`) sets the input field separator. So, we check if the line number is greater than one (`$.>1`) and if it is, add the value of `chr 39` (a `'`, thanks @josephR), to it. Finally we use `join` to connect each element in the array `@F` with `","` and print the resulting string.

Comment: Better than mine 8-(

Comment: @slm dunno, using the escape code is better practice I just couldn't be bothered to look it up and yours is shorter if you add the `2,$` as Kevin has.

Comment: For the Perl solution, don't you mean `-F'","'` and `join("\",\""...` as you did in `gawk`?

Comment: @JosephR. no because that fails on the first field and it turns out the syntax is clearer this way. I also found I had to escape the `"` for `-F` and it just got too complex. This will fail if the OP has quotes within the fields (and he does based on his other questions) but hey, that was not mentioned here :). By the way, I shamelessly stole `char 39` from you, hope you don't mind.

Comment: I don't mind at all. I stole the idea of representing `'` by its codepoint from @slm myself :). How would the Perl work in this case? Note that the OP states that there may be multiple commas inside the quoted fields.

Comment: Ah, yes, so he does. Crap then, I'll rewrite.

Comment: @JosephR. done, works for commas within fields now.

Answer (score 5):

Using Perl:

```
perl -pi -e '
             BEGIN{
                 $column_number = 2; # Change as needed
                 $column_number--;
                 $apostrophe = chr 39;
             }
             next unless $this_is_data++; # Skip the first line
             s@ ^((?:"[^"]+"\s*,){$column_number}) "@$1"$apostrophe@x
           ' your_file
```

This assumes your fields don't contain backslash-escaped quotes.

Comment: I love Perl and use it daily but when these solutions get posted it's like watching a air craft carrier pulling up to a frigate battle 8-).

Comment: @slm All fixed now.

Comment: @slm Strange. I tested it on a file exactly as provided in the example and it worked.

Comment: I see the issue, you're writing the changes back out to the file. Works now.

Answer (score 4):

A simple `sed` will do:

```
$ sed 's/","/","\x27/' afile
"col1","'col2","col3","col4","col5"
"value11","'value12","value13","value14","value15"
"value21","'value22","value23","value24","value25"
"value31","'value32","value33","value34","value35"
```

#### Details

We're searching for the first occurrence of `","` and replacing it with `` ","` ``. However escaping of the backtick can be tricky. So just put its hex escape code equivalent, `\x27`.

#### Your problem

This can be adapted like so to limit the changes to just rows you want.

```
$ cat <(head -n +1 afile) <(tail -n +2 afile | sed 's/","/","\x27/')
"col1","col2","col3","col4","col5"
"value11","'value12","value13","value14","value15"
"value21","'value22","value23","value24","value25"
"value31","'value32","value33","value34","value35"
```

Or you can skip the first line entirely, using `sed` if you know the trick 8-):

```
$ sed '2,$s/","/","\x27/' afile
"col1","col2","col3","col4","col5"
"value11","'value12","value13","value14","value15"
"value21","'value22","value23","value24","value25"
"value31","'value32","value33","value34","value35"
```

This tells `sed` to take only the 2nd line till the last line (`$`) and run those through the search and replace.

Comment: Sed can skip the first line without help, `sed '2,$s/...'`

Comment: @Kevin - yeah I just saw in yours, didn't know that trick

Comment: @Kevin - hope you don't mind, I added an example using `2,$`.

Comment: Of course not, I added your escape too